# XPath and XML: Multiple namespaces

Tags: xpath, xml-namespaces

So I have a document that looks like

```
<a xmlns="uri1" xmlns:pre2="uri2">
 <b xmlns:pre3="uri3">
   <pre3:c>
     <stuff></stuff>
     <goes></goes>
     <here></here>
   </pre3:c>
   <pre3:d xmlns="uri4">
     <under></under>
     <the></the>
     <tree></tree>
   </pre3:d>
  </b>
</a>
```

I want an xpath expression that will get me `<under>`.

This has a namespaceURI of uri4.

Right now my expression looks like:

```
//ns:a/ns:b/pre3:d/pre4:under
```

I have the namespace manager add 'ns' for the default namespace (uri1 in this case) and I have it defined with pre2, pre3, and pre4 for uri2, uri3, and uri4 respectively.

I get the error *"Expression must evaluate to a node-set."*

I know that the node exists.  I know that everything up until the `pre4:under` in my xpath works fine as I use it in the rest of the document with no issues.  It's the additional `pre4:under` that causes the error, and I'm not sure why.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**Resolution:**

Thank you all for your insistence that it's correct--it was.  But... in my code I had "pre4" as "64" (a variable) and it didn't like an integer for a prefix.  Changing it to "d" + myintvariable worked.

Comment: With the namespace registered in the exact way you described, that expression should select the `under` element you want. I think you need to provide more context's information.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but I can't see a definition for a pre4 namespace anywhere. Is that just because of a typo, or could that be the problem?

Comment: I can't think what else I would give.  Jon, I use nsmgr.AddNamespace("pre4", navigator.NamespaceURI) before calling the expression. (Yes, it's the right thing.)  Maybe the problem is that I shouldn't have defined what's sort of a second default namespace?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short C# application that successfully uses the XPath expression from your question and produces the correct result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that there may be a bug with the implementation that you are using to navigate the XML. Using [SketchPath](http://qutoric.com/sketchpath/), the following XPath navigated to the node successfully:

```
/def:a/def:b/pre3:d/def2:under
```

Could you try specifying different prefixes for the namespaces in the XPath? Otherwise, if performance isn't really an issue, and it's a unique node, you could just try `//under`

Comment: No, sadly no guarantee at all that it's a unique node.  I'm going to try out that sketchpath thing with the full document and the expression in question and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

**There is an error in your code, which you have not shown to us**.

**This C# console application:**

```
using System;
using System.Xml;


namespace Namespaces
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(
                @"<a xmlns='uri1' xmlns:pre2='uri2'>
                    <b xmlns:pre3='uri3'>
                        <pre3:c>
                            <stuff></stuff>
                            <goes></goes>
                            <here></here>
                        </pre3:c>
                        <pre3:d xmlns='uri4'>
                            <under></under>
                            <the></the>
                            <tree></tree>
                        </pre3:d>
                    </b>
                </a>"                
                       );
            XmlNamespaceManager nsman = 
                new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
            nsman.AddNamespace("ns", "uri1");
            nsman.AddNamespace("pre2", "uri2");
            nsman.AddNamespace("pre3", "uri3");
            nsman.AddNamespace("pre4", "uri4");

            Console.WriteLine(
                doc.SelectSingleNode("/")
                  .SelectNodes("//ns:a/ns:b/pre3:d/pre4:under",

                                nsman)[0].OuterXml
                              );
        }
    }
}
```

**when executed, produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<under xmlns="uri4"></under>
```